# What is the number of distinct 3 letter words out of different number of given letters?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

## Question

What is the number of distinct 3 letter words out of the following:

> `a` number of distinct `R`s
>   `b` number of distinct `G`s
>   `c` number of distinct `B`s

To form a single word we can use exactly three letters. Also, the main condition is that all three letters in a word shouldn't have the same letter. Other than this, any arrangement is possible. Quite obviously, if any 1 letter is used in forming a word, it cannot be used again. What maximum number of words can be formed if we have the given number of letters?

## My Answer

I tried using this formula but it doesn't work. Could you point out my mistake?

$$\frac{(a+b+c)!}{(a!\,\ b!\,\ c!)}$$

Comment: how do you know your formula is wrong? if you have code to test it, the pseudocode for this test would be helpful to post also.

Comment: The computer does not accept it. There are hidden testcases where this formula fails.

Comment: what do you mean "the computer does not accept it"?

Comment: I need to submit this problem as a code and then black box testing is done upon it.

Comment: $0 \leq a,b,c \leq 3$ right?

Comment: no. 0<= a,b,c <= 3*10^9

Comment: _???_ think this problem is not clearly stated. it seems to be saying, "of a large number of [x], filtered by criteria [y], how many are possible" but [x] seems unclear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30335/discussion-between-somnath-rakshit-and-vzn).

Answer (score 2):

The formula $\frac{(a+b+c)!}{a!\times b! \times c!}$ gives the number of
possible words with length $a+b+c$ in the case that the $R's$,$G's$ and
$B's$ are NOT distinct and the arrangement matters.

Approach:

We can assume $a\le b\le c$ due to symmetry. An upper bound for the desired number is $min(a+b,trunc(\frac{a+b+c}{3}))$. A lower bound is $a$.

Comment: I need 3 letter words only.

Comment: The given sample answer says that if we have 5 R, 4 G and 3 B, then the answer will be 4. **RRG, RGB, GRB, BGR**.

Comment: But then, how is the answer 4 for when a,b,c are equal to 5,4,3?

Comment: The problem has just been updated. The placement of letters do not matter. All 3 letter words which does not have all the letters same are allowed.

Comment: The problem says that for the given testcase, the **one possible way** to  form the words is RRG, RGB, GRB, BGR where R,G,B denote the letters of the words. We cannot form more than 4 words with the given number of letters. The question says **What maximum number of words can be formed if we have the given number of letters?**

Comment: We cannot assume a<=b<=c

Comment: min(trunc((a+b+c)/3) , a+b) is not the answer. It doesn't work always.

Comment: No idea.But this answer was rejected.

Comment: Yes. I set up the formula and submitted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30325/discussion-between-somnath-rakshit-and-peter).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I miss something, but the solution is just $\frac{(a+b+c)!}{(a+b+c-3)!}$

Edit: I missed the condition you have. The solution is $3!abc$

Comment: How do we get it?

Comment: If u dont want tge lettrrs to repeat, you have a choices from the firdt set, etc. Once youve selected, you have 3! ways to write them

Comment: The given sample answer says that if we have 5 R, 4 G and 3 B, then the answer will be 4. RRG, RGB, GRB, BGR

Comment: The problem says that for the given testcase, the **one possible way** to form the words is RRG, RGB, GRB, BGR where R,G,B denote the letters of the words. We cannot form more than 4 words with the given number of letters. The question says **What maximum number of words can be formed if we have the given number of letters?**

Comment: how can it be RRG if the letters must be unique?

Comment: and why not RBG in your example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30327/discussion-between-somnath-rakshit-and-alex).

Comment: not interested, sorry